# Saving sheets in excel to another excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with multiple sheets, and I want to save two sheets from the workbook to another new workbook.

I tried the below code, but it is copying only one sheet from my workbook to another one.

Could anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

```
Sub save()
Dim myworksheets() As String
Dim newWB As Workbook
Dim CurrWB As Workbook
Dim i As Integer
Dim path1, Path2 As String
path1 = ThisWorkbook.Path
Path2 = path1 & "\Saved Files\SW\"
Set CurrWB = ThisWorkbook
myworksheets = Split("BW", "Reason")
For i = LBound(myworksheets) To UBound(myworksheets)
Set newWB = Workbooks.Add
CurrWB.Sheets(Trim(myworksheets(i))).Copy Before:=newWB.Sheets(1)
newWB.SaveAs filename:=Path2 & Format(Now(), "WW") & " CW " & myworksheets(i) & ".xlsx"
newWB.Close SaveChanges:=True
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
MsgBox ("File Saved")
 End Sub
```

Comment: Move this line `Set newWB = Workbooks.Add` before your For loop.

Comment: What are you expecting to see happen with  Split("BW", "Reason") ? The delimiter is not present so you will have an array of one item surely? Why not simply say Array(...)

Answer (score 3):

Change this line `myworksheets = Split("BW", "Reason")` to `myworksheets = Split("BW,Reason", ",")`

Comment: changing this now i could see only one sheet saving.. Not two sheets

Comment: you need to modify your loop. please check mark's answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is within the loop.  You are creating a new workbook for each sheet then pasting the sheet into it, saving and closing.

Moving the new workbook creation and saving, closing out of the loop should solve your problem.

```
Sub save()
Dim myworksheets() As String
Dim newWB As Workbook
Dim CurrWB As Workbook
Dim i As Integer
Dim path1, Path2 As String
    path1 = ThisWorkbook.Path
    Path2 = path1 & "\Saved Files\SW\"
    Set CurrWB = ThisWorkbook
    myworksheets = Split("BW", "Reason")
    Set newWB = Workbooks.Add
    For i = LBound(myworksheets) To UBound(myworksheets)
        CurrWB.Sheets(Trim(myworksheets(i))).Copy Before:=newWB.Sheets(1)
    Next i
    newWB.SaveAs Filename:=Path2 & Format(Now(), "WW") & " CW " & myworksheets(i) & ".xlsx"
    newWB.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox ("File Saved")
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Amend those two lines:

```
Dim myworksheets() As String
myworksheets = Split("BW", "Reason")
```

To

```
Dim myworksheets() 
myworksheets = Array("BW", "Reason")
```